# How can I make a Yes/No combobox return true/false?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I am new to creating forms in Visual Studio and C#. But I made a UI that has some comboboxes where the DropDownStyle is DropDownList. The items shown is Yes and No. But I need to assign this as a boolean value to a property on some object ai and currently do this:

```
    if (cmbExample.Text == "Yes")
    {
        ai.isPacketType = true;
    }
    else if (cmbExample.Text == "No")
    {
        ai.isPacketType = false;
    }
```

I basically want to do something like this (or some other one liner):

```
ai.isPacketType = cmbExample.Text;
```

How do I link the Text Yes to the value true and No to false?

Comment: And if you can't use a checkbox, what's wrong with code that is more than one line? At least it makes clear what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
ai.isPacketType = (cmbExample.Text == "Yes");
```

Or if `isPacketType` is `bool?`:

```
ai.isPacketType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbExample.Text) ? (bool?)null : cmbExample.Text == "Yes";
```

Comment: The problem is that the combobox is empty as default. When the user clicks it, then there is only Yes and No to choose from. ai.isPacketType is null as default and not false, so I basically would have to do a ai.isPacketType = (cmbExample.Text == "No"); also. Wouldn't I?

Comment: That depends: what do you want `isPacketType` set to if the user doesn't select anything?

Comment: I want to force the user to select either true or false. False is not the default value. It's kind of a security, because it's important that I don't set any values for the user. It's for an XML document and the user has to fill out everything. So the property is not set at all. You would get a NullPointerException at this moment.

Comment: @Kasper: Set "No" as the default value of the combobox. In somewhere like your form's `Load` event, set its `SelectedIndex` property to the index corresponding to the "No" option before it ever gets displayed to the user.

Comment: Yes. I will do that. Thank you. But then I lose the validation that the user has actively chosen "No". But ok, that must be for another time.

Comment: @Kasper: I'm not sure how your original code worked either, then. You're going to have to either have a default value, or throw up a validation error message if they click "OK" without having selected a value in the combo box. Either way, you'll need an `If` or `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this and you're using databinding there's a neat little way to do it described in [this blog post](http://standotnet.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!11842CBE439F113B!117.entry). Basically you set up a couple of key value pairs:

```
private List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> GenerateYesNo()

{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> yesNoChoices = new List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>();

    yesNoChoices.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>("Yes", true));
    yesNoChoices.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>("No", false));    
    return yesNoChoices;
 }
```

Or in VB.Net:

```
Private Function GenerateYesNo() As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean))
    Dim yesNoChoices As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean))

    yesNoChoices.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean)("Yes", True))
    yesNoChoices.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Boolean)("No", False))

    Return yesNoChoices
End Function
```

and bind to this set of pairs. For full details follow the blog link.

Answer (score 0):

```
ai.isPacketType = (cmbExample.Text == "Yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course write it like this

```
ai.isPacketType = cmbExample.Text == "Yes";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you probably want to create a little wrapper class/struct around Boolean. You can then override the ToString() value to return either Yes or No.

The underlying value will stay the same, but the UI will display a different value by using the ValueMember and DisplayMember properties on a ComboBox.

This would probably be considered an MVVM approach, by adding a ViewModel on your data for making it look good on the UI, without driving it directly with any conditional code.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `ai.isPacketType = cmbExample.Text == "Yes"` (case sensitive), or `ai.isPacketType = string.Compare(cmbExample.Text, "Yes", true) == 0` (case insensitive).

Answer (score -1):

Cant you use the 'Checked' property, which will give you true is checked and false if unchecked:

> ai.isPacketType = cmbExample.Checked;

Comment: It's a combo box, not a check box.